# C++ Storing Items in Array and Setting each Token

Tags: c++, arrays

My name is Faith and I am a beginner programmer in C++. I am working on a project where I have to read in two file and be able to separate the items in each file to its own variable. The first file has two pieces of information separated by "," and the second has three pieces of information. So far, I think I've done well with reading the files and getting each line in the file. Also I've separated each item by "," now I am trying to store those items in its on variable. Please Help! I've tried starting this project over multiple times and this is the only method I know how to implement to do this.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Manufactuer{
    string upcode;
    string company_name;
public:
    void setupcode(string value){
        upcode= value;  }
    void setcompany_name(string value){
        company_name= value; }
    string getupcode(){ return upcode;}
    string getcompany_name(){return company_name;}
    
};

class Products{
    string product_num;
    string quantity;
    string product_name;
public:
    void setproduct_num(string value){
        product_num= value;  }
    void setproduct_name(string value){
        product_name= value; }
    void setquantity(string value){
        quantity = value;}
    string getproduct_num(){ return product_num;}
    string getquantity(){return quantity;}
    string getproduct_name(){return product_name;}
    
};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
        //opens the csv file
    std::ifstream mccodesfile;
    std::ifstream salesfile;
        mccodesfile.open("mccodes.csv");
        if(!mccodesfile){// file couldn't be opened
            cout<<"Failed: file could not be opened"<<endl<<"Press Enter to Close:";
            cin.get();
            return 0;
        }else
            cout<<"Successfully opened file!"<<endl;
    salesfile.open("sales.csv");
    if(!salesfile){// file couldn't be opened
        cout<<"Failed: file could not be opened"<<endl<<"Press Enter to Close:";
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }else
        cout<<"Successfully opened file!"<<endl;
    Manufactuer* upccodes;

    int count; //how many elements in the array
    int size; //how large the array
    
    count = 0;
    size = 2;
    upccodes= (Manufactuer*)malloc(size*sizeof(Manufactuer)); //Malloc dynamatically reserve memory for variable pointer    
        string line;
        while (getline(mccodesfile,line)) {// Taking every line from the file and putting in the variable line
            Manufactuer newcode = Manufactuer(); //creating a upcode object
            istringstream ss(line);
            string token; //setting up split values
            bool haveReadUPCode = false;
            while (getline(ss,token,',')){// Separated values by comma
                if(!haveReadUPCode){
                    newcode.setupcode(token);
                    haveReadUPCode = true;
                    
                }else{
                    newcode.setcompany_name(token);
                }
              
            }
            if (count == size){
                size = size * 2;
                upccodes= (Manufactuer*)realloc(upccodes,size*sizeof(Manufactuer)); //Double the size while keeping the same elements
            }
            upccodes[count++]= newcode;
     //       cout<<line<<endl;
            
        }
   for (int i = 0; i<count; i++){
     //   cout<<upccodes[i].getcompany_name()<<endl; //Prints Manufactuers name--Works!
       
   }
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    //    cout<<upccodes[i].getupcode()<<endl; //Prints UPCcodes--Works
    }
        Products* product;
    product= (Products*)malloc(size*sizeof(Products)); //Malloc dynamatically reserve memory for variable pointer
    
    while(getline(salesfile, line)){{// Taking every line from the file and putting in the variable line
        Products newProduct = Products(); //creating a product object
        istringstream ss(line);
        string token; //setting up split values
        bool haveReadProduct = false;
         while (getline(ss,token,',')){// Separated values by comma
         if(!haveReadProduct){
             newProduct.setproduct_num(token);
             haveReadProduct = true;
        } else{
                 newProduct.setproduct_name(token);
                 newProduct.setquantity(token);
             }
         }
         if (count == size){
         size = size * 2;
         product= (Products*)realloc(product,size*sizeof(Products)); //Double the size while keeping the same elements
         
         
         }
         product[count++]= newProduct;
         //cout<<line<<endl; //LINES ARE Printing!
         
         }
       }
    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++){
      //  cout<<product[i].getproduct_name()<<endl; //Prints Product name--Works
        
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++){
       //cout<<product[i].getproduct_num()<<endl; //Prints Product number--Works
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you required to use dynamic allocation (malloc) ?

Comment: What is the actual question? Which bit are you having trouble with?

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Comment: No I'm not required to use dynamic allocation(malloc). Any suggestions?